# Who are all these people killed at the end of Casino?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, casino

At the end of the movie *Casino*, we can see the [*Whacking scene*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQJhXNkzTiU) where several people are killed.<sub>[Alternative link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FZ2FA-epcE)</sub>

It is not very clear who they are, and why the Mob Bosses ordered their killing. They can't obviously kill all the staff of the casino which could include thousands of people.

So, who they are, and why specifically them, were ordered to be killed?

Comment: @BCdotWEB, thanks for the link, I'd seen it. I thought maybe I could have more details about who the guys are.

Comment: I don't know if all that are shown were featured in the movie before, but even then their identities are implied. The point is to show the extent of the carnage. The why is answered: "The aging bosses [...] decide to eliminate anyone involved in the scheme to stop them from testifying and prolonging their coming sentences".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Andy Stone**, killed by the two hitmen while leaving the steak house

- Who?

[image: Andy Stone]

> ACE: As far as the world was concerned, Andy Stone, **the head of the Teamsters' Pension Fund**, was a legitimate guy.

- Why?

> NICKY: As much as they liked him, I mean, **he wasn't one of us. He wasn't Italian. As far as they knew, he could have talked**. Otherwise, Stony might still be alive.

### John Nance, killed in his mansion in Costa Rica

- Who?

[image: John Nance]

> NICKY: The guys inside the counting room were all slipped in there to skim the joint dry. They'd do short counts, they'd lose fill slips. They'd even take cash right out of the drop boxes. And **it was up to this guy right here, standing in front of about two million dollars, to skim the cash off** the top without anybody getting wise, the IRS or anybody.

Nance is the money courier who brings the cash to the bosses in Kansas City.

- Why?

> NICKY: The first one to skip was John Nance. He found a nice, warm secluded place in Costa Rica. He thought nobody would find him there. **But, then, his kid got nabbed by the Feds for drugs, and so naturally the bosses were afraid he'd come out of hiding just to save his kid and give 'em all up.**

### Two Counters, killed by the two hitmen in the desert

- Who?

The Count Room executive

[image: Count Room Executive]

The Counter #2

[image: Counter #2]

They were both well aware of the scheme, as Nicky says:

> NICKY: **The guys inside the counting room were all slipped in there to skim the joint dry.** They'd do short counts, they'd lose fill slips. They'd even take cash right out of the drop boxes.

### Richie, killed in his car

- Who?

[image: Richie]

- Why?

He is a Tangiers Executive also aware of the scheme like the other guys.

---

[Script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/casino.html)